# List index permissions

Tags: git, permissions

I can add execute permission to a file:

```
chmod +x alfa.sh
```

Then I can list the updated permissions:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 Steven None 0 Dec 19 22:10 alfa.sh
```

I can also add execute permission to the Git index:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x bravo.sh
```

This allows me to change the permissions in the index independent of the actual file permissions. Normally you would notice these differences right away with
`git status`, but if you have `core.filemode = false`, Git will not notice the permission differences.

How can I list the execute permissions stored in the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 2262de0c121f22df8e78f5a37d6e114fd322c0b0 0       alfa.sh
100755 2262de0c121f22df8e78f5a37d6e114fd322c0b0 0       bravo.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plumbing:

```
$ git ls-tree -r @
100644 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    alfa.sh
100755 blob e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391    bravo.sh
```

Or:

```
$ git diff-tree --summary $(git mktree </dev/null) @
 create mode 100644 alfa.sh
 create mode 100755 bravo.sh
```